# How to pass json data to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

What if i want to pass json array to view for autocomplete purpose?

Is ViewBug enough good?

What is best way to do it?

And another question.

My page divided by a few parts. One group parts is static content(it is not editible, something like span tags) which i pass to view through  viewmodel. Other group is  dynamic content (inputs, select and so on).

So for such type page we are using following ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
     public ViewModelPart1 Part1 {get; set;}
     public ViewModelPart2 Part2 {get; set;}
     public ViewModelPart3 Part3 {get; set;}
}
```

and in View we have following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


      <span>@model.Part1.Age</span>   
      <span>@model.Part1.Name</span>   

.....

     <div>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Part3.CountryName)<br />
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x..Part3.CountryId)
     </div>

     <button id="SaveButton" type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

So when user press save button we are getting back our view model except all fields which enclosed in `<span>` tags. Sure it's not good because of we cannt restore our page after validation fail. For resolve this problem we can use hidden fields `<span>@model.Part1.Age</span>  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Part1.Age)`. Unfortunally it's make HTML code dirty and i think it's not good practice. So how to do it right? Also there are many variations of this issue(passing data partial views, save state when we add new data dynamically and so on). I wish to found cookbook which can help me to learn basic asp.net mvc patterns.

Comment: you should only ask one question

Comment: @Rune FS It's two side of one question about good asp.net mvc practices